# How to view HTML coverage report using Cobertura Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, cobertura

I want to generate and view a coverage report for a Java-Maven project.

I've added the following to `pom.xml`:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <formats>
          <format>html</format>
        </formats>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

When I run `mvn cobertura:cobertura` it builds successfully and reports to the console that `Cobertura Report generation was successful` but I can't find the report.

If I `cd` into `target/cobertura` I find a file called `cobertura.ser` but I have no idea what to do with it.

**Edit:** After re-examining the docs, thanks to Andreas_D, I've added the `<reporting>` tag, but get the same result.

Comment: Use jacoco-It is much better than cobertura http://technikes.com/how-to-generate-code-coverage-report-in-java-jacoco-graphical-report/  You also get report in 3 formats namely HTML,CSV and XML

Comment: @sakshamagarwal Well, I asked this question is 2011, for the record. In 2017, I'm thankful to not be dealing with Java/Maven/XML nonsense.

Comment: May be it will help other developers. Hope to solve any of your error in future.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the plugin's documentation, [there's an example](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html#Usage). Pretty sure that you have to add a `<reporting>` element to actually produce the report.

Comment: Good catch, but I still get the same result. I've updated the question.

Comment: @FarmBoy - you need to add the cobertura plugin in the `<build>` section (to execute cobertura) and in the `<reporting>` section (to create the report. And you may have to add the `site` goal (`mvn cobertura:cobertura site`) to actually build the (html) site

Comment: Hmm, the `site` target creates a dependency problem. It can't find `org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-11`. Our repository has `alpha-10`. Why is it looking for this at all?

Comment: @FarmBoy - you'll have to solve the dependency issues. "Execute" the pom on a machine that is connected to the internet, then import the new local repository from that machine to your repository (looks like your disconnected from the web)

Comment: I'm forced to go through my companies internal repository, and I understand that this is my problem. I'm just baffled why adding the `site` target would create new dependencies.

Comment: @FarmBoy - that's maven :-) If your curious - there's one goal you can call that just shows the dependency tree for a pom (don't know by heart - check the maven site), then you can see *who's* using the artifact

Comment: @andreas-d probably, you are talking about `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Need to look at ..\target\site\cobertura\index.htm and NOT ..\target\site\cobertura\cobertura\index.htm

Answer (score 19):

This in the Build section:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

And then this in the Reporting section:

```
<reporting>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ... 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <check></check>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</reporting>
```

Execute `mvn cobertura:cobertura`

Then look for **index.html** inside the **target/site/cobertura/** folder.

Comment: Hope this helps someone. I'm not revisiting this old question.

Comment: I think <plugin> should be wrapped in a <plugins> element. If so, suggest the answer is amended as it doesn't work

Comment: Yes peter.murray.rust, you're right and I was under the impression that developers won't just copy paste the entire thing but place the necessary code at the right place. Adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried here in my project, you can do the following also:

a) run mvn cobertura:cobertura
b) it should generate a folder called 'site'
c) you can open the index.html (inside site/sobertura folder) in whatever browser and inspect the results of coverage.

Answer (score -1):

If nothing works - Try this
http://technikes.com/how-to-generate-code-coverage-report-in-java-jacoco-graphical-report/  you can get code coverage report in html and xml format

This is amazing as I publish my report in html and xml

Comment: This question is far to old for me to have a chance at reproducing the problem, so I won't be voting on new answers.

Comment: But this answer is not for increase my vote.May be it will help other developers. Hope to solve any of your error in future.Thanks

Comment: This answer actually doesn't address the question about cobertura, it provides a way to do it with another plugin.